# Is there a tool that can calculate the time of sunrise?

Tags: resources, sunrise

From time to time I enjoy taking hikes in the mountains to see a beautiful sunrise and sunset. When doing this, I always guess when the sun will rise that day and then I plan my tour accordingly. But this is not always that easy, especially in the mountains, when other mountains can delay a sunrise dramatically.

So I'm looking for a tool or resource where I can enter the coordinates of the mountain I want to visit and that then calculates the time of sunrise and sunset.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This web page should do the job, and also has a draggable map and list of cities if you want to select one of those rather than entering in manual co-ordinates.

http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/grad/solcalc/

Comment: This page doesn't seem to take account of topography, though. For instance, it gives me the same sunrise time for the peak of Denali and for a point in the valley 10km north of the peak. As the question points out, mountains can make a huge difference to the timing of sunrise and sunset.

Answer (score 6):

If you're old-school, here is a device I just learned about today (and it should fit into your pack):

[The Sunsetwheel.](http://www.sunsetwheel.com/)

It's a sliderule type device, and may take a few minutes to learn how to use it, but it can give you data without having a smart phone on you at all times.